# Consultar si dos fechas se solapan

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo que hacer una consulta que consiste en comprobar si la fecha de inicio que me insertan y la fecha de fin que me insertan no está comprendida en otro artículo existente, es decir:

```
Artículo {
Id:1
Nombre:'mesa'
F_ini: 1/7/2018
F_fin : 31/7/2018
}
```

Entonces si quiero insertar una silla, no puede estar comprendido entre 1 y el 31, es decir :

F_ini `29/7/2018` F_fin `8/8/2018` no me vale porque el inicio está comprendido,

Ocurre lo mismo con la fecha de fin `25/6/2018` fecha fin --`29/7/2018` , la fecha de fin está dentro del bloque.

Por último `1/1/2018` -- `31/12/2018` Tampoco me vale, porque en su interior estaba comprendida la otra fecha.

```
Select * from articulos where F_ini > fecha_inicio and f_fin < fecha_fin;
```

El problema es que esto no me vale porque no puede comprobar los 3 tipos de casos y no sé cómo hacerlo...

Comment: Si quieres comprobar 3 casos distintos, necesitarás hacer más casos "WHERE". que la fecha_inicio, esté fuera del rango, que la fecha_fin este fuera del rango, y luego que si la fecha_inicio es menor que la F_ini la fecha_fin también sea menor que F_min, y si la fecha_ini es mayor que F_fin que la fecha_fin también sea mayor que la F_fin. Te lo pongo en una respuesta, para explicarlo mejor.

Comment: A ver...sigo sin entender tu pregunta. Tu que necesitas? que la consulta te devuelva los articulos cuyo periodo se solapan al que intentas agregar? o que no devuelva nada? Porque si analizo tu consulta, lo que hace es devolver los productos cuyas fechas se solapan, y en ese caso mi respuesta te sirve.

Comment: Quiero encontrar algo con la select, porque si encuentra, es un error,  y debo informar, en caso contrario (el nuevo producto no está en ese rango de fechas) hago el insert.

Comment: En ese caso, prueba mi respuesta. Te va a devolver cualquier producto cuya fecha se solape por cualquier lado con la que intentas agregar.

Comment: >= No me deja meter esos operadores, son de tipo fecha, no tipo enteros, estoy usando el tipo date con PostgreSQL

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias, la consulta funciona perfectamente, me equivoqué al ponerlo en java. Gracias !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es comprobar si dos periodos de tiempo se solapan. Para eso existe una fórmula muy sencilla:

```
(FInicioA <= FFinB) and (FFinA >= FInicioB)
```

Esta formula es inclusiva, es decir, si las fechas coinciden las considera como que si se solapan, si no lo quieres así cambia `<=` por `<`y `>=` por `>`.

Resumiendo, tu consulta sería algo como:

```
Select * from articulos where F_ini < fecha_fin and F_fin > fecha_inicio;
```

Comment: El select que has puesto es práticamente el select que tiene él, xD, por lo que le he entendido quiere comprobar que esas fechas están antes o después del periodo, y según tu condición no comprueba eso, si no si las fechas pasadas (fecha_fin y fecha_inicio) están dentro de otro periodo. Sería más algo como: SELECT *
    FROM articulos
    WHERE (fecha_inicio < F_ini AND fecha_fin < F_ini)
    OR (fecha_inicio > F_fin AND fecha_fin > F_fin)  Bueno, y faltaría comprobar que la fecha_fin realmente sea posterior a fecha_inicio

Comment: @DiegoMartin revisa el select que he puesto yo y el que tienen el. Te aseguro que no tienen nada que ver :)

Comment: Él comprueba si F_ini y F_fin están dentro de fecha_inicio y fecha_fin y tú justo al contrario. Pero el concepto es el mismo, se comprueba que un periodo esta dentro de otro.

Comment: @DiegoMartin otra cosa es que el op quiera comprobar que las dos fechas **no** estan superpuestas. En ese caso es posible que haya entendido mal su pregunta

Comment: Con el ejemplo que tenía de la mesa, si la consulta devuelve datos , porque está dentro de ese rango, entonces debería informar de error.

Comment: @DiegoMartin el OP comprueba que un periodo está completamente dentro de otro. Mi consulta comprueba si están superpuestas por cualquier lado (completamente, por la derecha o por la izquierda). Creo que es una diferencia notable. De todas maneras, esperaremos a ver si el OP aclara la pregunta.

Comment: @Pikoh  SELECT * from articulos where (fc_inicio <= :endDate ) and (fc_fin >= :startDate) me dice que da conflictos si inserto un año válido del 2010

Comment: @EduBw No entiendo que significa "da conflictos". Por un lado revisa  en la base de datos que no haya fechas nulas que podrían darte problemas. Por otro, en todo caso pon el mensaje de error que te da exactamente. Si te falla con un año en concreto es por los datos que tienes en tu tabla, revisa que sean correctos.